# Can I use Eclipse Dependency injection (DI) in normal Java Model?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, pde

I am trying to write Java model which will act as model for Eclipse RCP.  This model I should be able to run without UI also (i.e in command line). I wanted to use (Explore, I am new to this) DI supported by e4. Can any one guide me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in Eclipse bug [323075](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323075) the e4 RCP startup currently always wants to create a Window. So it does not look like you can use it for a 'headless' RCP.